# Load data from serialization to listbox

Tags: vb.net, serialization, deserialization

I am able to write to the file perfectly... however I am having trouble reading from file and inserting read data into a listbox.

```
Public myData As New MySettings
Public saveFile As String = ("mysettings.ini")


 'SAVE INFO TO SETTINGS FILE

    Dim fs As Stream = New FileStream(saveFile, FileMode.Create)
    Dim bf As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()

    For l_index As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim l_text As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(l_index))
        bf.Serialize(fs, l_text)
    Next


    fs.Close()
    Return
```

This is the part where I am having trouble...

```
'LOAD INFO FROM SETTINGS FILE

    Dim fs As Stream = New FileStream(saveFile, FileMode.Open)
    Dim bf As BinaryFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()

    For l_index As Integer = 0 To saveFile.Count - 1
        Dim l_text As String = CStr(saveFile(l_index))
        'myData = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), CType(myData))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(myData)
    Next

    fs.Close()
    Return
```

Any help at all would be appreciated, even a point in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if the answer helped, please upvote/click the checkmark so this is removed from the Unanswered list

Answer (score 0):

The ListBox `ObjectCollection` (Items) is not marked as serializable, so you cant serialize the entire thing at once.  You may have encountered this and used the loop to serialize each item.  The loop does appear to serialize each item, but I don't know how you can deserialize in a loop - you wont know how many items there are, nor will the Serializer.

Rather than one item at a time, you could copy the `ListBox` items to an array and serialize the entire thing:

```
Dim ary(lb.Items.Count - 1) As Object
lb.Items.CopyTo(ary, 0)

' OpenOrCreate!
Using fs As New FileStream("C:\Temp\lbitems.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    bf.Serialize(fs, ary)

End Using        ' close and dispose of stream
```

Deserialization is just the reverse:

```
Using fs As New FileStream("C:\Temp\lbitems.bin", FileMode.Open)
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    Dim myAry = bf.Deserialize(fs)

    lb.Items.Clear()
    lb.Items.Add(myAry)

End Using
```

You can make it a bit simpler using a `List(of String)` and assign it as the DataSource.

```
Private myLBItems As New List(Of String)
  ...
' fake items to add
myLBItems.Add("Foo")
myLBItems.Add("Bar")
myLBItems.Add("Option")
myLBItems.Add("Strict")

lb.DataSource = myLBItems
```

Using the List as the DataSource, you dont have to copy items from here to there - whatever is in the List will appear in the ListBox.  Serialization is simple too:

```
bf.Serialize(fs, myLBItems)
```

Since Deserializing returns an Object, you need to cast it (`Option Strict`):

```
myLBItems = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), List(Of String))
```

---

Note: This may not be doing what you want at all.  Your code is serializing what is in the ListBox after converting it to String.  Later, it looks like you want to Deserialize to a `MySettings` Type.

If `MySettings` is something like a Name and Value pair (or collection of them), probably half the data and all the Type information will have been lost.